# Azure Blob Storage using Https

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I am looking out encrypt data in-transit when uploading files to Azure Storage.
How can I use `StorageClient` to make https call to Blob Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define secure HTTPS protocol in connection string:

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccount;AccountKey=myKey;`